# TYPO3 Extbase: Operand should contain 1 column(s):

Tags: sql, typo3, extbase, operand

i want to add() a message to the database in my controller. That works so far.

I've got a column called "message_tags" in which i save an array.

The array is:

```
array(5 items)
0 => 'dfsdfsd' (7 chars)
1 => 'dsfsdf' (6 chars)
2 => 'sdfdsf' (6 chars)
3 => 'asd' (3 chars)
4 => 'google' (6 chars)
```

Now, TYPO3 throws me an error:

```
Operand should contain 1 column(s): UPDATE   
tx_xxx_domain_model_message SET message_text='dfdsfsdf', 
message_tags=('dfsdfsd','dsfsdf','sdfdsf','asd','google'), mobile_os=('android'), 
tstamp='1355846301', sys_language_uid=NULL WHERE uid='73'
```

The array is constructed in my controller (i know this is far away from good coding):

```
foreach($messageTagsArray as $key => $value) {
              $mergedTagArrayValues[] = $value;
            }
            foreach($storedTagsList as $key => $value) {
              $storedTagsListValues[] = $value;
            }
            $mergedTagArray = array_merge($mergedTagArrayValues, $storedTagsListValues);
            $mergedTagArray = array_unique($mergedTagArray);

            $message->setMessageTags($mergedTagArray);
```

Is that a bug?

Thanks for your help!

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TYPO3 apparently is trying to use your array as a part of the query, which fails.

Fastest workaround for this will be just serializing the array in your `setter` (`setMessageTags($array)`) and unserializing in the `getter` (`getMessageTags()`) in such case Extbase will save it as a string, however you'll keep possibility to work with array without any additional steps.

Comment: Apparently this was the issue. But when i serialize that array, i'm getting a very weird string. Something like this:                     a:4{i:0;s:8:"xyvcxyvc";i:1;s:7:"xyvyxvc";i:2;s:8:"yxvcyxvc";i:3;s:0:"";}

Comment: That's common serialized array - if you unserialize such string, you'll get your PHP array back. For storing arrays that's the best option anyway